# Template for c# + reactjs + typescript + token-based-authentication

Tags: reactjs, typescript, .net-core, jwt

I'd like to create application with reactjs on frontend, .NET Core web api on backend, some database, and token-based authentication.
I want users to be able to sign-up, sign-in, sign-off, recover password.

I cannot believe I need to build all this from scratch. There should be set of building blocks that I just need to put together. Are there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/) seems to be a right answer for security user flows.

[react-adal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-adal) enables AAD B2C with react.js

[.NET Auto Generated Controllers](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-web-api-crud-logics-using-entity-framework-without-writing-single-code/) enables very thin transparent back-end, allowing to have the entire business logic in react.js.
The only business logic I manually created in .NET is authorization. It verifies that the user is eligible to read/write data he/she is reading/writing.

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with this as well. If you're still looking, I have a boilerplate I'm creating to address authentication / authorization with React + .NetCore:

https://github.com/moh704/AuthenticationExample

I have the signin and authorization employed so far as this is the hardest part for me. I'll soon be adding sign up / log out features. I'll also put in sql server database scripts to generate user registration tracking and password storage.

Comment: why Azure Active Directory B2C did not work for you? It is free and works nice.

Comment: I'll definitely give B2C a shot when I host my next app through azure. I was questioned a few times in interviews about this topic so I went ahead and created an example.  My solution is primarily focused on the React side and I left the .net core validation to be implemented by whom ever would make use of the project. Once a user signs in (use azure b2c), we would still need to protect the reactjs routes to ensure the user's token has not expired.Otherwise, without having an HOC protecting the routing, a user can just change the url and navigate to it on the site we host.